# The communication among multiple controllers

Tags: sdn, openflow, mininet

I want to have a simple **multi-domain** topology in mininet in which each domain is controlled by a single controller and the communication among domains will take place through controllers. So I will have a **distributed** control plane.

Imagine this topology:

```
   c1                    c2
    |                    |
    |                    |
   s1                    s2
  |  |                  |  |
  h1 h2                h3  h4
```

My question is about the communication among these controllers. Imagine h1 wants to send a packet to h3. This packet will reach c1 at first and c1 should send it to c2 so that it will reach h3 through c2. How can controllers send data to each other? (I'm using Floodlight controller) Is it possible to use a simple switch between each pair of controllers, so that they can communicate through this switch?
Something like this:

```
   c1 ------- s0 ------  c2
    |                    |
    |                    |
   s1                    s2
  |  |                  |  |
  h1 h2                h3  h4
```

So I want to know if this is a correct way to have a multi-domain topology and enable data communication between controllers?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is really too broad. There are multiple ways of doing this, and you have not provided enough specifics to give an answer. Remember that SDN is still a term looking for a definition. Different SDN technologies do things differently, and we would need to know more specifics about what you propose.

Comment: @RonMaupin I added some details. Is it clear now or it still has some issues?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the characteristics of SDN is that the controllers are not in the forwarding path.  So, s1 and s2 need a path between them, not the controllers.

Comment: But since each of these switches is located on a separate domain, is it OK to implement this topology by providing a path between s1 and s2?

Comment: That is the only way you can get traffic from h1 to h3.  All SDN networks connect to something outside their domain.  Otherwise, they're very limited.